# Strange output in C Program

Tags: c, gcc, output, getchar, putchar

So I am just starting to learn C, I am using gcc if that makes any difference, and for some reason this simple program is giving me weird output:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    main()
    {
        int c;

        while (c == getchar() != EOF)
        {   
            putchar(c);
        }   
     }
```

I save it and use :!gcc % then :!./a.out in vim, when I type in any letter then Enter, it just gives me "^^" as the output. I searched around and couldn't find anyone else with this problem, and it's copied straight out of K&R so I don't know what could be causing this error, does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: You sure it was `while ((c == getchar()) != EOF)` and not `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)` ?

Comment: No you're right I retyped it wrong here, but I had it right in the original program, I'm going to edit the original post

Comment: What you have there now doesn't compile.

Comment: He has one extra bracket before c.

Comment: OTOH, with the missing `)` added and the `==` fixed it *does* compile, and works as advertised. Not a `^` in sight, unless I type one. (And then I get to see another -- still "as advertised".)

Answer (score 0):

Ned Stark's answer is right, I had 2 equals signs and that's what was causing the weird errors. Thanks for all the help guys! Ned, if you want to post an answer I'll mark yours as correct, otherwise I'll mark this as correct in two days.

Comment: We all know ;-) but can you figure out why you got the unexpected result? I.e., the double `==` caused it but *why* did it do so?

Comment: The `while` loop was never executing, was it?

Comment: Hmmm yeah I'm not sure, I have no idea what "^" has to do with anything at all....

Comment: you need to change your code like this  while (c = getchar() ). It would work perfectly